# Algorithm to process this data faster? (sorting a 4.2M size stack)

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, handler, game-engine

Situation: at the end of procedurally generating my game's world, I am left with a *2048^2* (~4.2 million) size Stack of tiles. I then need to calculate where in my handler's list of stacks they need to go. Here is my method:

```
public static final void addTile(Tile t){
        for(int i = 0; i < sections.length; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < sections[i].length; j++)
                if(sections[i][j].contains(t.x, t.y)){  //<-- determine which list according to tile's pos
                    world.get(i).get(j).get(TILE_LIST).push(t);
                    return;
                }
    }
```

There is a `Rectangle[][]` that corresponds with each spot in the 'world' `arraylist`. As you can see, this is an `O(n^2)` loop that needs executed **4.2 million times.** Even with **4 threads running concurrently** processing all the tiles takes ~20 seconds.

This isn't a completely unviable processing time, but I think there must be a better algorithm. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be great to know what your "contains" does. If it is some kind of lookup, then I would suggest to store the data differently (for better reverse lookup). If it is actually a function, one would need to know the structure to "invert" it.

Comment: @JFMeier Meier It's the Rectangle contains method, as I stated, "sections" is a Rectangle[][].

Comment: Are the sections stored in sorted order? If so perhaps the loops could be replaced with a binary search.

Comment: (1) I don't see why the second code would be faster, it should be slower due to IO, which is a big bottleneck usually. (2) How is `Rectangle.contains()` implemented? Is it `O(1)`? If not, this is not O(n^2) code... (3) I suspect you do this loop iteratively, and by doing so, you might do a lot of extra work multiple times. Is it the case?

Comment: @amit it is the default Java rectangle, and for (1) yeah I've just been experimenting with all kinds of things, it is fairly slower. (3) yes the method is called by: addTile(stack.pop); essentially. The issue is the stack is not in sorted order to begin with.

Comment: Are the sections non-overlapping?

Comment: are your rectangles overlapping? if not and if they are actually arranged in a grid (of equally sized cells) then you could just "hash" your coordinates to the right rectangle index: `int i = (int)((t.x - minX) / width), j = (int)((t.y - minY) / height);`

Comment: As @JFMeier wrote, without reorganizing the data you might not be able to achieve anything. Or - perhaps it already is organized somehow: how are `sections[i][j]` and `sections[i][j+1]` related? And `sections[i][j]` and `sections[i+1][j]`?

Comment: When asking questions like this, try to give all the information: say that rectangle is java.awt.Rectangle, describe how rectangles are located, etc. So many people here ask you questions because it's totally unclear what you really need

Comment: @BeyelerStudios no they are not, they are in a perfect square grid. This sounds like a good approach.

Comment: Why  you did not write about perfect square grid in the question? With this information our answers become less useful. And your question is a kind of XYZ problem.

Comment: @MBo because I thought a Rectangle[][] would be assumed to be a grid? That's what people use Rectangle[][] 99% the time for? But whatever you can downvote anyway, I have the best answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An r-tree, as mentioned by MBo, is a good spatial index for arbitrary point/poly searching, however, since we are looking for rectangles (axis aligned polygons) you would likely be better off using a quad-tree (or oct-tree in 3 dimensions).

[image: quadtree visualization]

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63536/how-do-shapes-rectangles-work-in-quad-trees

Comment: yes this looks like a better approach. Honestly to better understand the question I should rather explain it as a square grid of rectangles, and we're checking for 4.2m random points placed somewhere on the grid.

Comment: after reading that you have an area already composed of arbitrary (100% packed) rectangles, this could be optimized further by simply  keeping a list of bounds of rectangle index along x axis (some would overlap)
and a list of bounds of rectangle index along y axis (overlap). Finding the  value that is shared by both results (exactly 1 will match this).

Answer (score 1):

You certainly need  a good data structure for fast searching rectangles that contain given point.

[R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) is intended to treat such queries very fast.

[image]